# Sparql Update query for edit value of a property

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, apache-marmotta

i tried to update a value of a query in my DB on marmotta. I have a lot of resources like this:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://desktop-pqb3a65:8080/marmotta/resource/7e31bb9e-5dee-4f44-b082-9f770d465ea0">
<hasContentPath xmlns="http://www.kiwi-project.eu/kiwi/core/">D:\Software\Marmotta\marmotta-home\resources\56\cc\73\56cc736b-f597-47e8-9ffc-f37c3dbf66be</hasContentPath>
<about xmlns="http://schema.org/">Fondamenti di Informatica</about>
<name xmlns="http://schema.org/">Hello World!</name>
<author xmlns="http://schema.org/">EduOpen</author>
<audience xmlns="http://schema.org/">Qualsiasi</audience>
<actor xmlns="http://schema.org/">Gianni Vercelli</actor>
<description xmlns="http://schema.org/">Accenni storici sulla nascita del calcolatore</description>
<width xmlns="http://schema.org/"></width>
<height xmlns="http://schema.org/"></height>
<duration xmlns="http://schema.org/"></duration>
</rdf:Description>
```

I want to edit the `hasContentPath` field, i have a value like this:

```
D:\Software\Marmotta\marmotta-home\resources\56\cc\73\56cc736b-f597-47e8-9ffc-f37c3dbf66be
```

I'd like to edit and insert a value like :

```
resources\56\cc\73\56cc736b-f597-47e8-9ffc-f37c3dbf66be
```

Can you help me? i tried this query:

```
PREFIX schema:  <http://schema.org/>

DELETE { ?resource <http://www.kiwi-project.eu/kiwi/core/> 'D:\Software\Marmotta\marmotta-home\resources\56\cc\73\56cc736b-f597-47e8-9ffc-f37c3dbf66be' }
INSERT { ?resource <http://www.kiwi-project.eu/kiwi/core/> 'resources\56\cc\73\56cc736b-f597-47e8-9ffc-f37c3dbf66be' }
WHERE
{ ?resource schema:name 'Hello World!'
}
```

Comment: You want to change the property value of `hasContentPath` so why don't you set this in your query? You used `http://www.kiwi-project.eu/kiwi/core/` as a predicate, but this isn't a property at all.

Comment: You don't say what you do get.

Comment: How does this relate to Virtuoso?

Answer (score 0):

Single `\` in strings are for escape sequences.  Unlike the linux shell, `''` strings have escapes as well.  `\S` is illegal as an escape — strictly speaking, that's a syntax error.  It seems to be interpreted in some way, but it is unlikely to be the characters `\` and `S`.